# How can I gain access to my Mac's command prompt from my pc command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, osx-lion, remote-access, telnet

I was wondering if there was a way that I could gain access to my Mac's terminal window from my PC. I was thinking along the lines of telnet but I've never done it before and I'm having a hard time finding any material on it so I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Why don't you RDP in?

Comment: can't rdp from windows to lion. You can VNC in, but only if the user isn't logged in (its stupid). Problem is, if I log out, my terminal services on the mac go down. So I need a way to operate remotely. I think I may have just got what i was looking for though. putty/ssh

Comment: SSH is always the way!

Comment: Citrix Xen will allow RDP (or so it claims) - from any windows, mac or mobile platform

Comment: System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote Login -> Enable it
Then just ssh in with a Windows SSH client using your username.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this pretty quickly once I knew what I was looking for. I simply enabled remote management on my mac and now I can use the mac command prompt remotely without needing to VNC or logout.